# How do I send a module to a Powershell Start-Job?

Tags: powershell

I send in a module to `Start-Job` but it seems to be empty.
Why isn't it filled with my `start` method?

```
$m = New-Module -ScriptBlock{
        function start(){
            "started"
        };
    } -AsCustomObject

$m.start()

Start-Job -ScriptBlock{
    $module = $args[0]
    "<argsO:$module>"

} -ArgumentList $m
```

I run the above and then:

```
PS C:\temp> job 510 | Receive-Job -Keep
```

to get:

```
<argsO:>
```

Alas, the $module seems to be empty.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$module` variable is being populated, it just doesn't produce any output. You can check by putting `$module | gm` inside your `Start-Job` and you will see that it is a `PSCustomObject`:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock{
    $module = $args[0]
    $module | gm

} -ArgumentList $m

Get-Job | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

Unfortunately what you're trying to do won't work because the object gets deserialized when its passed as an argument and as a result it loses its methods, so attempting to call `.start()` within the job returns:

> [Deserialized.System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not
>   contain a method named 'start'.

Comment: Dang! Do you know of a way to accomplish my goal? - send a module/object into a job?

Comment: If the module is already present in one of the default module directories on the machine the job is running on, you should just be able to load it.

Comment: One can do a `Start-Job -InitializationScript{Module-Import 'MyModule.psm1' -Force}` to achieve loading a module for every job.  
But... that is not the same as the module `$m` I try to send because such a module can have internal variables I set at the caller. I can send this variable through `Start-Job -ParameterList` but prefer not as I wish it to be private to the `$m` module.